# Hiding X axis on graph with ZedGraph lib

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+, zedgraph

I want hide X axis on my graph.
Here is my code for it:

```
zg1.GraphPane.XAxis.IsVisible = false;
zg1.AxisChange();
zg1.Invalidate();
```

But i have problem with it.

My graph:

[image]

After hidding X axis:

[image]

Any idea why i have this issue?

Answer (score 7):

```
zg1.GraphPane.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsZeroLine = false;
```